# How to use continuation monad transformer with spawn/exec in purescript?

Tags: callback, purescript

I want to execute a command using `spawn` in `Node.ChildProcess` but i have no clue on how to hook the the function which spawns the command and the rest of the application with `spawn`. I have a vague idea that i need to use `ContT` for hooking up the error and success callbacks and am not able to figure out the data pipeline as a single program.

This is the program I am trying to write -

1. Wait for a request (let's say as an HTTP server)
2. On request, write something to a file
3. Fire a terminal command
4. Collect output from terminal command
5. Send response

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the easier solution and use Aff. I have an example of how I'm doing spawned child processes here: https://github.com/justinwoo/vidtracker/blob/b5756099a4f683d262bc030d33b68343a47f14d7/src/GetIcons.purs#L44-L54

```
curl :: forall e.
  String
  -> String
  -> Aff
      _
      Unit
curl url path = do
  cp <- liftEff $ spawn "curl" [url, "-o", path] defaultSpawnOptions
  makeAff \e s -> do
    onError cp (e <<< Exc.error <<< unsafeStringify)
    onClose cp (s <<< const unit)
```

I have another example here where I'm collecting the output: https://github.com/justinwoo/simple-rpc-telegram-bot/blob/09e894c81493f913fe316f6689cb94ce1f5056e6/src/Main.purs#L149

Comment: Thanks! Will check out the examples and get back to you. 

Can you please explain how the types line up even after taking care of error, data and close callbacks from the stream returned by spawn?